# Image field unlimited values doesn't save just the first image..the others disapear on save

Tags: entities, media

I have a weird problem that appeared with my latest drupal installation
I have a content type with some image fields that have an unlimited value (I can upload more images to the same field)
When I press SAVE only the first image remains saved..the other ones..don't
No error is given..
Nor on screen nor on logs..

my drupal version is 7.8
memory limit 96M
Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8g PHP/5.2.11 with Suhosin-Patch
Mysql 5.1.38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be that is a bug from Drupal fixed in the last release (7.9) according the [release note](http://drupal.org/node/1322736).

Comment: Yes, it really did solve it :) thanks.. Lucky for me that they released it just yesterday night